# MySql, how to get last msgs to/from different users

Tags: php, mysql

My table looks like this

```
id INT
from9 VARCHAR 12
to9 VARCHAR 12
message TEXT
datetime9 DATETIME
```

from9 and to9 are users' ids. Obviously if Susan (ID:susan) sends a message to Jack (ID:jack), row in MySql table will look like:

```
55 (Auto-increment INT)
susan
jack
Hello Jack how are you doing?
2016-11-14 22:22:22
```

If Jack sends message back, from9 and to9 will be invese. As you can see I am saving one message for both parties (this is fine). I would like to list all "last" messages either send to me OR sent by me and I am having problems building such query. I was thinking to do workaround and have more queries: 1) get msgs sent to me  2) get msgs sent by me  3) put all those msgs in a set and do final query where I read those IDs.

Is it possible to build one query for this?

Comment: Are you really making new tables for each chat that occurs between two people? `ID:jack` and `ID:susan` just does not seems valid. An ID is an integer, an integer you can join to multiple tables, like the ID that belongs to jack and susan.

Comment: Use an `ORDER BY` in your query against the `DATETIME` column to display  'last' messages.

Comment: this is bonkers

Comment: you actually have columns named from9 and to9 and datetime9?    
`select * from table where from9='jack' OR to9='jack' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: Some of you didn't understand please read my comment to Avan below.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope you will get answer from this query

```
SELECT max(datetime),msg FROM `message` WHERE from9="a" or to9="a"
```

Here "datetime" is my date field name in db and am generating query with a message which is sent or receive by the user "a" last time

Comment: Not ok, because I need last message sent either to me from Mike or sent from me to Mike. Your example will return me 2 messages (me to Mike, Mike to me). I only need LAST message sent between two of us. I am thiking of doing 2 queries and UNION between them, add unique key for me/him and removing duplicates except latest msg.